# make a copy of all arguments in a batch

Tags: windows, batch

Since the values %1, %2, %3...etc in a batch can't be modify, I need to create a copy of it.

Question:

```
Q1: How to create a copy in one go?  
    Not like SET cp1=%1, SET cp2=%2, ...etc.

Q2: Can one access the variables in this copy by a for loop, which is similar to
    "FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (...)"
```

Comment: In the for loop why can't you set a variable to %%A, then do what you want with it?

Comment: Because I need the modified value to pass them to another bat.

Comment: However, just create var1~var9, assign them to %1~%9, using `FOR %%A IN (var1 var2....var9) DO` works for me.

Comment: Ah, so you need to pass along *multiple* modified values to a second batch file, and thus cannot copy them one by one to the same variable in a loop and modify them?

Comment: yes, exact what I want to do, this is the problem.

Comment: Yes, I got it, you need multiple modified values together. A for loop with a single variable to which each value is copied in turn won't help in this case. So what's wrong with your solution? Edit: You know, you've asked 3 batch-related questions, and I think they're all part of the same problem. If so, why not simply create a *single* question stating clearly what it is you're actually trying to do, rather than ask piecemeal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t figure out a *really clean* way to run the second program (or batch file, or whatever) with the modified argument list, but I believe I have a good 88% of what you want:

> `@echo off`
>   `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`
>   `set i=0`
>   `for %%A in (%*) do (`
>       `set /a i+=1`
>       `echo arg !i! is %%A`
>       `set var!i!=%%A`      // This sets `var1=%1`, `var2=%2`, …
>                           // and, of course, you could modify the values at this point.
>   `)`
>                           // And at this point, `%i%` is the number of arguments.
>    *(Other stuff)*
>             ︙
>   `for /L %%J in (1, 1, %i%) do (`
>       `call :kludge var%%J`           // `var%%J` is “`var1`” or “`var2`” or …
>       `echo arg %%J is !this_value!`  // This iterates through the original args,
>                                     // and, of course, you could modify them here, too.
>   `)`
>    *(Other stuff)*
>             ︙
>   `exit /b`
>
> `:kludge`
>   `set this_value=!%1!`
>   `exit /b`

Comment: Thanks for the trick `set var!i!=%%A `, I will try it.

Comment: 100% what I want. Make a copy of all argument in one go!

Answer (score 0):

As someone mention on SO

> %* seems to hold all of the arguments passed to the script.

it was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357315/get-list-of-passed-arguments-in-windows-batch-script-bat)

**Update 1:**

```
:loop
@echo %1
shift
if not "%~1"=="" goto loop
```

You can save them all to variable e.g

```
SET ARGS_LIST=%*
echo %ARGS_LIST%
```

Comment: But I can't not modify these values, so I create a copy. This is what I asked here.

Comment: u can loop through all arguments by the upper code (update 1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to do this, but you can make a copy of the parameters using:

```
set parms=%*
```

The above will work for most situations, though there are some cases where it will fail. For example, it will fail if a parameter includes unquoted special characters.

The parameters can safely be iterated using a FOR loop if and only if none of the parameters contain `*` or `?`, and all parameters containing space or special characters are quoted.

```
for %%P in (%parms%) do ...
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't still modify the value of %%P, because %%P will be %1, %2, ...etc